# Trouble with installing hadoop 2.2.0 on ubuntu server

Tags: linux, database, ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to install hadoop 2.2.0 on my server in ubuntu. I followed a tutorial. I've    finished all the steps but upon running the command:

> start-dfs.sh

i keep getting this error:

```
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.utf-8)
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh: line 55: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop/bin/hdfs: Not a directory
Starting namenodes on []
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh: line 60: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh: Not a directory
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh: line 73: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh: Not a directory
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh: line 108: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop/bin/hdfs: Not a directory
```

Comment: Can you check your `$HADOOP_INSTALL` environment variable?It could be it is pointing to the wrong directory.